# How to setting multiple email SMTP in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, email, smtp, phpmailer

I have used contact form 7 (WordPress plugin) for some forms in my website. Now I receive all email forms in **info@mysite.com**, which is okay. But, there are  another option in contact form 7 which is autoresponder (Mail 2). I want to use **no-reply@mysite.com** email here.

This means that, when people send me an email using my website contact form then they will immediately got reply from **no-reply@mysite.com** and this email must have to avoid spam folder. If you have any idea about this please share with me.

TIA

Comment: in the configuration of the 2nd e-mail, you can set a sender different of the receiver of the first e-mail.

Comment: We all know that, there are some plugins for configure Wordpress email. (e.g: WP SMTP). But, all plugin can configure one mail only. Now what is your idea for second mail? Are you means that manual confirmation system?

Answer (score 0):

You can setup multi smtp servers by using [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/multi-smtp/) plugin.

Demonstration:
Here you go with the screen shot. Install this plugin. Go to the multi smtp section. Now put your first smtp server detail and you are done. After that another section will appear for Server 2

[demonstration image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiD6Q.png)

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.